# ASP to Access dababase - SQL join query

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

Imagine two tables in the same Access database;

```
Transaction
 - Date
 - Time
 - TransactionNumber
 - UniqueID
 - Exception (boolean)
```

(TransactionNumber is sequential integer for records of the same day, and then starts again from 0 each day. Key field is UniqueID)

```
Exceptions
 - ExceptionNumber
 - Date
 - Time
 - TransactionNumber
 - ExceptionReason
```

(ExceptionNumber is sequential integer for records of the same day, and then starts again from 0. TransactionNumber is the same value from Transactions where Date is the same in both tables)

Where Transaction.Exception is TRUE, a record relating to that Transaction will also appear in Exceptions.

I want to output ALL records from Transaction, and where Transaction.Exception happens to be TRUE for a record, then I want a column which shows the Exception.ExceptionReason. For the other records, it should be blank.

I've no idea how this is possible. If you joint the two tables via the Date and TransactionNumber fields, you'll only see records where Transaction.Exception = TRUE.

Comment: Since an exception relates to a specific transaction would it not be better to place the transactions uniqueID into the exceptions table instead of `TransationNumber` and `Date`? You could specify this field as an FK to the transaction table.

Comment: Exception can only have one row for each combination of Date + Transaction Number, as any one given Transaction can be an exception, or not an exception. Only one exception possible per transaction. Also, I cannot amend the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like a `LEFT JOIN` could accomplish what you want.

```
SELECT
    t.[Date],
    t.[Time],
    t.TransactionNumber,
    t.[Exception],
    e.ExceptionReason
FROM
    [Transaction] AS t
    LEFT JOIN Exceptions AS e
    ON
        t.[Date] = e.[Date]
        AND t.TransactionNumber = e.TransactionNumber
```

Comment: Surely just `TransactionNumber` in the join is sufficient.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Ben said "TransactionNumber is sequential integer for records of the same day, and then starts again from 0 each day".

Comment: Thanks! This worked in Access when I re-did it via the Query Builder. I also worked out how to get it to display records only where the exceptiontype is not 43, 44, 45 or 46 (by adding "Or Is Not Null" condition after the In list. :)